# Реализация связи многие ко многим в c# (windows forms)

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Имеется бд со связью многие ко многим. Работаю с ней на форме 'Данные о маршруте'

Не знаю как записать sql-запрос, чтобы отображались выбранные пункты определенного маршрута(т.е. записанные в tRoutesPuncts) в текстовом виде (правый cxomboBox).

P.S. В левом comboBox отображаются все маршруты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну на много легче будет использовать Entity Framework. Но я так понимаю это курсовая то вы врятли успейте передалать на нем  а по поводу запроса но мне кажется связь как то верно составлена

Comment: пробните так SELECT * FROM tRoutes,tPoutesPuncts WHERE tRoutes.ID_Route = tPoutesPuncts .ID_Route;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поискал ещё немного в интернете и сам нашел ответ на собственный вопрос.

```
int id=Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)this.bsForRoutes.Current).Row["ID_Route"])
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct, tPuncts.sPunct FROM dbo.tRoutesPuncts INNER JOIN tRoutes ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route = dbo.tRoutes.ID_Route" +
" inner join tPuncts ON dbo.tRoutesPuncts.ID_Punct = dbo.tPuncts.ID_Punct WHERE tRoutesPuncts.ID_Route=" + id, connection);
```